# Laravel GroupBy multiple columns with date

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have these fields in my table, I want get the data by month of the selected year & type_id, then SUM the amount on each month.

Ex: `selectYear = 2019`

Here is my `account_table`

```
id | type_id | amount |  kind   | created_at
 1 |    2    |   200  | expense | 2019-01-15 10:14:31 
 2 |    2    |   400  | income  | 2019-01-15 10:14:31 
 3 |    2    |   300  | expense | 2018-01-15 10:14:31
 4 |    5    |   100  | expense | 2019-02-15 10:14:31 
 5 |    5    |   200  | income  | 2019-03-15 10:14:31
```

this what I expected output.

if kind is expense the amount is -,
if kind is income the amount is +

Ex. on the month of Jan.

id 1 has 200 expense, and id 2 has 400 income

formula `-200 + 400`

```
 Jan | Feb | Mar | ... so on
 200 | 100 | 200 | ... so on
```

I hope I delivered and explain well, I am stuck on this functions, please I need help,

UPDATE.
Expected OUTPUT
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simething like `$q = Model::select(
            DB::raw('sum(amount) as sums'), 
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') as months")
  )
  ->groupBy('months')
  ->get();`

Comment: @sta, thank you for you response dude, but it's not groupingBy type, and also how can I display it in the table? I have table Jan - Dec in thead, I got confused. Thanks

Comment: please try this ..`Model::select(DB::raw('type_id as type_id'),DB::raw('sum(total_amount) as total_amount'),DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTHNAME(created_at) month'))
        ->groupby('type_id','year','month')
        ->get();`

Comment: No, I still got the same Type in my Table, I expect in one row it's list the Jan - Dec total amount, because right now the data is correct but I can't figure out how can I insert it in table. I will update my post, and add image.

Comment: You need to format data..   Sql query will not give you expected output what are you looking for... i think there are more task need to do...

Comment: Use `MONTHNAME` instead of `month`

Comment: What's missing in my code, to achieve my expected output? because I want to display it in table. Thanks

Comment: @Marky are you here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222212/discussion-between-abdullah-al-noor-and-marky).

Answer (score 0):

Try following query on your account table:

```
Account::select(
  DB::raw('SUM(IF(kind = "expense", amount * -1, amount)) as sum'),
  DB::raw('YEAR(date) as year'),
  DB::raw('MONTH(date) as month'),
)
->where('type', $type)
->where(DB::raw('YEAR(date)'), $selectYear)
->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(date)'));
```

You will get data like this:

```
[
  [ sum: 400, year: 2020, month: 7, ]
  [ sum: 500, year: 2020, month: 8, ]
  ...
]
```

Comment: @dude I didn't get any result on my console.log.

Comment: It depends what year and type you specified

Comment: I also edited post to sum up depending on kind ( `income` and `expense`)

Comment: It's only getting the current month

Answer (score 0):

first, you must define or parse your year and month to numeric value. ex : January become 01, February become 02 etc.

in example :

```
$year = 2019;
$month = 01;
```

And you can use this :

```
$total = 0;
$data = DB::table('account_table')->whereMonth('created_at',$month)->whereYear('created_at',$year)->where('type_id',$type_id)->get;
foreach($data as $value){
   if($value->kind == 'income'){
      $total += $value->amount;
   else{
      $total -= $value->amount;
   }
}

return $total;
```